# HTMLHelper addCrumb method not available

Tags: php, cakephp, html-helper

I would like to use the addCrumb method in my Layout to automatically add controller links. I tried this but the Html-Helper-Object in the Layout didn't contain the addCrumb Function. Then I tried to use the function in the beforeFilter in my AppController to set the Link but this wont work too (no error given). At last I tried to use an element to make this happen, but this didnt the job (error method not found).

I am using CakePHP 2.0 - has anybody an idea to solve my problem (without changing the *.ctp files by hand)?

PS: Using $this->html->addCrumb() in my specific .ctp-file works great.

Answer (score 0):

To have access to HTML helper methods such as addCrumb, you must make sure the helper is loaded for whatever action you want to use it in. Simply do `$this->helpers[] = 'Html';` in your controller (in an action or in your AppController to add it universally).

Comment: Thank you but that didnt worked. It is not the problem to load the Helper (i tried to use the Html->link method wich worked well) - i just cant use the addCrump method.

$view = new View($this);
$html = $view->loadHelper('Html');
debug($html->link('link', '#')); //worked
debug($html->addCrump('test', '/test/')); //failed => Warning (512): Method HtmlHelper::addCrump does not exist [CORE/Cake/View/Helper.php, line 165]

Comment: Just checking Toniab, you keep saying addCrump... I hope you're not mispelling it, as the function is called addCrumb. I just want to double check that this isn't the problem in your code.

Comment: Thank you, that did it! English is not my first language :S

Comment: Don't worry. I'm glad you fixed the problem. Please consider accepting this answer if you found it to be helpful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work